# $SO(3)$ has a subgroup $U(1) \times U(1)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

I am wondering - and asking you - whether there is a subgroup $U(1) \times U(1)$ of the Lie group $SO(3)$. Equivalently, I can reformulate it from a geometrical point of view: does there exist a torus $T^2$ embedded in a 3-dimensional sphere $S^3$?

Furthermore, which is the explicit form of this embedding?

Comment: No, the rank (maximal commutative subgroup/subalgebra) of $so(3)$ is 1. The Lie algebra can be represented by skew-symmetric matrices, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the cross product $\times$.

Comment: On the other hand, topologically, you certainly can embed $T^2$ into $S^3$, it just won't be a subgroup. Writing $S^3$ as $\{ (w,x,y,z) : w^2+x^2+y^2+z^2=1 \}$, the set $w^2+x^2=y^2+z^2=1/2$ is a torus.

Comment: Your reformulation is not equivalent in two respects: first, it doesn't require any respecting of group structure, and second, $S^3$ is $SU(2)$, not $SO(3)$ (which is $\mathbb{RP}^3$).